# Which bug tracking and project management tool does Stack Exchange use?

Tags: discussion, technology

Which bug tracking and project management tool does Stack Exchange use?

Does it uses any of the existing open source tools or a premium paid one? Or better, have they created a tool themselves to manage this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't speak for everyone; it depends on the group — but we generally use some combination of chat rooms, [Trello](http://trello.com), our meta sites with tag filters, Gmail, Google Drive, [Fogbugz](http://fogbugz.com)… and a Magic 8-ball.

Comment: thanks `trello` seems interesting

Answer (score 4):

The definitive source for similar questions is "[Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)" but no mention's made of any bug-tracking or project management tools.

However, I strongly suspect that they use [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/) as it's the flagship product from one of the founders first company (Joel).

Answer (score 0):

Community team almost certainly uses [zendesk](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277258/can-we-view-the-internal-se-support-tickets-and-if-not-can-the-link-please-be-r/277260#277260). Us mere mortals don't see what happens internally, of course, but chances are there's some degree of use of that, presumably in conjunction with [trello](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291031/what-features-did-the-community-team-discuss-have-implemented-or-have-denied-l)