# Can we view the internal SE support tickets, and if not can the link please be removed?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, email

I just noticed this today when looking at my gmail inbox:

> [image]

Of course I clicked the "View ticket" button, just to reach a dead end: (on https://stackexchange.zendesk.com)

> [image]

I don't have email/password account of that kind, and couldn't see any option to log in using OpenID, even Stack Exchange OpenID, as in the real Stack Overflow site.

I clicked "Sign Up" and provided name and email (same email from which I sent the request) however was greeted with:

> [image]

"A user has already signed up with the given email"?? But not me!

Not giving up yet, I reached https://stackexchange.zendesk.com/auth/v2/login/password_reset and filled my email, got the promising "Email sent" message.... but no email landed in my inbox or spam folders. And that is where I gave up and decided to post here.

So, how can we view that ticket, if at all? If it's supposed to be used only internally by SE employees, can it please be removed? (I mean the link gmail shows, not the tickets system itself. :))

Comment: Well, I could sign up.

Comment: @Patrick interesting. Have you ever sent an email to Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow, or submitted a "contact us" form? (which is the same behind the scenes)

Comment: Yes, but I guess it never made it to the system. It was related to a MSE post, so maybe they didn't duplicate it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Note:** This question and answer are now obsolete, as we no longer use ZenDesk for support services (although our account is still open while we continue migrating stuff away from it through the end of 2018). We have switched to Freshdesk, which does not allow non-staff to login or create accounts and does not even have an option for these smart Gmail buttons.

---

ZenDesk is the ticketing system the Community Team currently uses.

I wasn't aware that it sent that "view ticket" link, but **I just edited a setting, which should stop it from being sent out again.**

By e-mailing us, either directly or by using the "contact us" page, the system will automatically create a pseudo-account without a password linked to your address, which is only used internally for us to be able to organise all the e-mails for us.

ZenDesk, unfortunately, offers us no possibility to just disable the Web Portal. This means that anyone who, like you, is able to find it, should be able to set an account on ZenDesk and follow the status of their tickets from the portal, instead of from the comfort of their inbox.
However, we'd really rather not have the portal, so we don't prompt you to register there, or even link you to it — or at least we thought we didn't!
Your messages sometimes jump from one employee to another, and back, and we change its status between these changes too. However, this is something that, ideally, you should not be seeing — only because these statuses only mean something to us, and we don't want our users to see their tickets randomly changing status without any reply back from us. As such, we've disabled the option that allows a user to then request a password to the automatically created account.

You're getting that error precisely because of that. And Patrick was able to create an account because he used an e-mail from which he had not sent us any e-mails in the past. As I mentioned, anyone can do that, as long as their e-mail is not yet taken. However, we see no benefit in doing that, since you'll only see what will seem like random status changes.

Comment: @JNat just found that I'm not the first to notice. Can you please post official answer here as well? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312088/stackoverflow-contact-us-option-view-ticket (or wait until you have a final answer. :))

Comment: Okay, updated it! And will reply to that other post too, @ShadowWizard ;)

Comment: That's what I suspected. We're also using third party support system at my work place (SpicrWorks) so I'm familiar with "private notes" and similar things, that means the client better not see the internals - but still, was hoping for some secret glimpse. Thanks a bunch for the fix, will keep an eye!  :)

Comment: Even if you're able to create an account and submit tickets using it, the only glimpse you should be able to see is the public replies to your own tickets. Nothing different from what you'd see by interacting with us normally.