# Is there an history of my tickets/correspondence initiated from the "Contact Us" page?

Tags: support, contact

I'd like to know if there is a log that I can access (within Stack Exchange, without looking in my mailbox) reporting my usage of [the "Contact Us" form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) across the SE sites.

I believe that the content of any correspondence wouldn't be accessible – since personal or sensitive information can be exchanged through that channel – but are the metadata present somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no such public log. The contents of the form are fed directly into an internal ticketing system; you can also provide a different email address than the one you used to sign up.

Note that if you inspect the form, you see that a link to your profile is submitted as well; this is necessary when requesting accounting merges, but is also useful sometimes to provide context for the person handling the ticket.

<sub>(Disclaimer: I'm not a Stack Overflow employee; the information above comes from the knowledge I obtained through the years here.)</sub>

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277260/152859

Comment: SE doesn't expose their Zendesk server to the public; judging from other companies that do, it's possible to view a history of support tickets you filed if the company makes it public.

Comment: (judging from the linked question, it appears that one *can* indeed have access to the tickets, but only provided that –for some inconceivable reason– he/she had created an account on a particular external ticketing site *before* making the first contact to "Contact Us". This is of course a border-case exploitation of something that SO/SE doesn't have control on, so yeah, at the end of the day there is no public log)

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316857/162102) is right; that information isn't stored on-site.  *And you wouldn't want it to be.*

The contents of your message to SE are private between you and SE.  The "contact us" form is, among things, the escalation path we advise people to use if they want to complain about a moderator.  It's important to be able to tell them that the moderator they're complaining about won't be able to see the correspondence.

There are probably other reasons that people might want to contact SE privately, but that's a big one.